# Recording a Surface using MediaCodec

Tags: android, opengl-es, ffmpeg, glsurfaceview, android-mediacodec

So, In my application, I am able to show effects(like blur filter, gaussian) to video that comes from Camera using [GPUImage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) library.

Basically, I (library) will take the input from the Camera, get's the raw byte data, converts it into RGBA format from YUV format, then applies effects to this image and displays on the `Surface` of `GLSurfaceView` using OpenGL. finally, to the user, it looks like a video with effects applied.

Now I want to record the frames of `Surface` as a video using [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API.

but this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964179/in-android-how-to-pass-a-predefined-surface-to-mediacodec-for-encoding) says that we can not pass a predefined `Surface` to the `MediaCodec`.

I have seen some samples at [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) where he is creating `Surface` using `MediaCodec.createInputSurface()` but for me, `Surface` comes from the `GLSurfaceView`.

So, how can I record a frames of a `Surface` as a video?

I will record the audio parallelly, merge that video and audio using FFMPEG and present to the user as a Video with effects applied.

Answer (score 9):

You can see a complete example of this in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).

In particular, the "Show + capture camera" activity records camera output to .mp4.  It also [demonstrates](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg) applying some simple image processing techniques in the GL shader.  It uses a `GLSurfaceView` and a convoluted dance to keep the recording going across orientation changes.

Also possibly of interest, the "Record GL app with FBO" activity records OpenGL ES rendering a couple different ways.  It uses plain `SurfaceView` and is much more straightforward.

Comment: is it possible to record video in background (Service) using MediaCodec, I do it with FFmpegFrameRecorder right now and it works fine, I start my activity, then I reset Camera onPreviewFrame callback from Activity to Service method and I get bytes in Service to able record it with FFmpeg. But what about MediaCodec all those GL Views stuff?