# How to add date watermark over video coming from Android camera?

Tags: android, camera

I'm a camera embeded developer, and trying to develop an Android APP to capture video and provide preview at the same time. Now I want the preview has date watermark on it.

As it in embeded system, there is specialized hardware module to handle the watermark osd task. But on Android, is it possible to manipulate the raw image adding watermark? And how long it will cost?

Will ffmpeg or gstreamer be helpful?

Comment: If your device runs Android, special hardware to handle watermark seems unnecessary. If you want to embed date watermark in video, you have two choices: build it into the camera driver, so that all recording apps get it, or take care on your app level. For the latter option means that you use ffmpeg to record the video.

Comment: @AlexCohn thank you for your help! I think I should pick the second option. In the first optionk, the modification over camera driver is not portable and other camera APPs will be effected.

Comment: If this satisfies your requirements, doing it in your app is much easier. Actually, you don't necessarily need 3rd party library, as ffmpeg. You can simply [employ MediaCodec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21531653/192373).

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks a lot. I will have a try.